# What happen when you stir a cup of coffe?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have a cup of coffe, i add sugar to it and then i stir it. Why the flavor is homogeneous in all the liquid? I would expect to see the distribution of sugar following lines arround the fluid and not uniformlly distributed in the fluid.

A conceptual answer is fine but (if you have the time) a more mathematical answer is always welcome.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Are you asking why nature coarse grains rather than to preserve phase space volume elements? Because classical mechanics is not a correct description of matter at the $\mu$m-scale in hot liquids.

Comment: I might be wrong but i think that sugar grains are big enough to be considered classical

Comment: It's not the size of the sugar grains that leaves the scale of applicability of classical mechanics, but the "Baker's transformation" during stirring makes the filaments of the liquid (and, more generally in phase space) thinner than the diffusion scale for your selected observation time. When that happens the filaments, which have a very high spatial frequency, get coarse grained (diffusion can move perpendicular to the classical motion) and that's when the approximation breaks down.

Comment: That is an interesting topic. I did not know about it. By any chance do you have some bibliography to recommend about it?

Comment: An experiment is worth a thousand words: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p08_KlTKP50. Laminar flow in a highly viscous liquid can be "unmixed". If you wait for a while, the machine couldn't do it, anymore because the diffusion would have been irreversible. Slightly more theoretical: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian), which formalizes the notion that a phase space volume element can be smeared our over the entire phase space, even if its volume stays the same. This, however, requires Hamiltonian dynamics, which diffusion does not obey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querido beto, sugar not only get mixed by convection, or fluid transport, as you do when you revolve the spoon, if that were the case you would be right. But sugar also transport to the liquid through diffusion (more precise mathematical description [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion)). Even if you do not revolve the coffee with a spoon, diffusion will act fast enough to, say, edulcorate your coffee in about 16 minutes.

Comment: +1 for the successful use of the word "edulcorate" in a physics context.

Comment: @CuriousOne you are not that bad as you like to look like, hahaha :)

Comment: Help! I am discovered! What am I going to do? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Sugar has a solubility in water of 909 g/1 L at 25 °C (wikipedia). Even if coffee is not water, let's take this as an estimate. In other words, if you do not heavily overload coffee with sugar, the sugar will get dissolved. The kinetics of this process are not known to me, but in general it seems fairly quick. The reason you stir is to distribute the water and sugar so that there are no local regions around the sugar where the sugar concentration is very high and dissolution thus very slow.
As soon as the sugar is dissolved, diffusion (in probably good approximation, Fickian diffusion $\dot{c}=D \Delta c$) sets in and distributes the dissolved sugar all throughout the cup as has been pointed out in the other answer.
If you want to see the effects of the fluids actual flow patterns, try putting something in that does not mix.